# Drupal ajax calls do endless redirect

Tags: taxonomy-terms, ajax, users

After moving my drupal installation to another domain (and server) ajax calls end up beeing redirected from the login-page to the target and back until the timeout is reached.

[image: Firebug log]

Why the target redirects the request to the login page and how to stop this?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436592/drupal-ajax-calls-do-endless-redirects). Thanks

Comment: Did you tried to clear caches (Drupal and browser)?

Comment: I tried both, but it didn't help.

Comment: any ajax modules installed?

Comment: Nope. I only moved it to a new location (new domain, new server).

Comment: sorry, what I meant is, are using - originally - any ajax modules?

Comment: No, i have not used any ajax modules.

Comment: It looks like it fixed itself. Thanks though!  ;)